# Django Class property spitting HTML to be displayed in model's Admin page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a class property that vomits some HTML:

```
class Task (models.Model):
    def test(self):
        return """<img border="0" alt="" src="/%s/%s/%s" />""" % (UPLOADS_DIR, GRAPH_DIR, "task.svg")

    test.allow_tags = True
```

How can I easily feed the returned HTML into the model’s admin page? It works for list_display() page. I tried to make a custom widget for the test() for its model page but my widget has failed to actually display the image. I don't want to solve this problem by making a custom template for this model. Basically I'm looking for a custom form or widget that just puts any HTML that test spits out into model's admin page without modifying the output of the property.

Any thoughts?

Thanks a lot!

Eras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you're not keen but I think overriding the template is going to be the best way to go.

A widget is associated with a particular field but your `test()` method isn't. And again django forms are just concerned with fields - they're about sending data back to the server - not presenting data - that's views and templates.

It shouldn't be too messy doing this by overriding a template. If you want it really clean, you could simply extend the existing template and then add your field at the bottom. Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) on overriding admin templates. It's quite simple to override a specific template for a specific model.

Comment: I wish there was a simple way to do it through a widget. I ended up modifying a template for this last night and it worked but I feel it could have been much better to keep things out of the template. :(